# ¿Por qué decimos "confundir la velocidad con el tocino"?

Tags: expresiones, españa, coloquialismos

En España es común decir en tono algo jocoso que alguien *está confundiendo la velocidad con el tocino* para decirle que está mezclando cosas muy diferentes.

> - Cristiano Ronaldo no puede haber defraudado a Hacienda. Al fin y al cabo es un gran futbolista.
>   - A ver, no confundamos la velocidad con el tocino: evadir impuestos no tiene nada que ver con meter goles.

Me pregunto: ¿por qué se eligió "velocidad" y "tocino"? Ambas son extremadamente diferentes incluso en su sonoridad.

Comment: Could it be related with the fourth meaning given in the [DRAE here](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZwfLUJz)?

Comment: Interesante esa cuarta acepcion. Siempre pense que a diferencia de "confundir las churras con las merinas" (que son dos tipos de ovejas) esta expresion hacia referencia a dos cosas completamente distintas (tipo "confundir la ley de la gravedad con la panceta de cerdo"). Se ve que hay mas en el origen del a expresion de lo que aparentaba...

Comment: Pues he borrado mi comentario pensando que me he equivocado, en el DRAE aparecían como si fueran lo mismo

Comment: Interesante, no aparece la expresión en el CORDE, y en el CREA la aparición más antigua es de 1984, así que es bastante reciente.

Comment: Corrección: en la hemeroteca de la BNE se encuentra la expresión en [un diario de 1937](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0004916760&page=1&search=velocidad+tocino&lang=es): "A cierto ministro de Instrucción Pública que se las daba de erudito enciclopédico, oímosle en una ocasión confundir la velocidad con el tocino." Y en [otro de 1932](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0001345772&page=7&search=%22velocidad+con+el+tocino%22&lang=es): "¡Arma candida... no confunda la velocidad con el tocino!"

Comment: En Cuba se usa una variante de esta frase: "no confundas la gimnasia con la magnesia", que me parece más acertada teniendo en cuenta el parecido de las palabras y lo distinto de su significado.

Comment: El diccionario de la real academia recoge "**confundir el culo con las témporas**" como sinónimo de "_confundir la velocidad con el tocino_", y su uso es muy antiguo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the DRAE for *tocino* we read, amongst others

> 4. m. En el juego de la comba, saltos muy rápidos y seguidos.

and if like me you did not know *comba*

> 2. f. Juego infantil o ejercicio físico que consiste en saltar por encima de una cuerda que se hace pasar por debajo de los pies y sobre la cabeza de quien salta.

After a bit more research I found in the following [blog](https://detodalavidalarues.blogspot.co.uk/2016/09/pan-carne-vino-y-tocino.html)

> Pan, carne, vino y tocino...
> ino, ino, ino, ino...

And which she goes on to explain as

> Ésta es una canción que empieza pausadamente, pero conforme nos vamos adentrando en ella, se va acelerando, llegando al paroxismo cuando se canta "ino, ino, ino, ino". Debemos cantar y dar con la cuerda a un ritmo similar, de manera que cuanto más deprisa cantemos y demos con la cuerda, más rápido tendrá que saltar el protagonista de nuestra historia. Al llegar casi al final, al saltador le resulta muy difícil seguir el ritmo, y lo más habitual es que falle.
>
> -Y si falla, ¿qué pasa?
> -Pues que otro ocupa su lugar, como es lógico.

So it seems that this is a chant which children skipping used and that they speeded up on the *ino* syllable. The point, as she explains, is so that the game has an end and someone else gets a go. In England we had a similar chant "Salt, mustard, vinegar, pepper".

There is a whole collection of skipping chants [here](http://craaltaribagorza.educa.aragon.es/canciones-de-comba) collected by a school and including some variants of the one I quote above.

If this is the origin then when it began it might have been familiar to people as comparison of two similar things but as time passes and one meaning is forgotten it now seems to compare two very different things.